# Incorrect time in Eclipse. How to change it?

Tags: android, eclipse, datetime, frameworks

No idea why, but my Eclipse v 3.5.2 (that I use for Android development) seems to have the wrong time.
Logs in the LogCat window are a few days out. And more annoyingly if I do a `Calendar.getInstance()`, it will return that same wrong date/time.

I'm on Windows 7 64bit and my system HAS the correct time!

Any idea if this is configurable somewhere?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you see in the logcat is the time on your device/emulator, not the computers time. If you use an emulator, chances are that it has the wrong time.

Just go to the device/emulators preferences as you would do on a real phone and set the correct time *(usually start at the homescreen, press the `menu` key, select `Preferences -> Date and Time`)*. This should solve the issue.

Comment: Looks like I'm having one of those duh moments! It's so obvious when you know it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Happens to the best of us. Glad I could help. :)